# How to return using ContentResult within a Navbar (partial View)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP.NET MVC C# at home with a basic C# programming. I am trying to create a list of customers, where I can click on each customer and it will show this customer name in a new view page. However, when a new viewpage appear, the customer name is there but no NavBar and other layout frames.

Here is my Code:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var customers = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        if (customers == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return Content(customers.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are returning `Content` as result not view. You should have a view named Customer details named like **Details.cshtml**:

```
@model YourNameSpace.Models.Customer
<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
```

and in your controller action you should be returning a View :

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var customer = GetCustomers().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

    if (customer == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(customer);
}
```

Hope it gives you some clue how to approach it.

Comment: Why not name the view "Details"? That way it would be the same as the action and you could omit the string when calling View().

Comment: @kay.herzam agreed, it should be details by convention

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much! ^_^